# Force file link to open as a preview in instead download nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

This code is downloading the files instead preview how can I fix this please guide

Thanks

res.download('/path/report.jpg', 'report.jpg')

Answer (score 0):

Use `sendFile` instead.

```js
res.sendFile('/path/report.jpg')
```

Comment: Yeah, that's true but even some images are downloadable do we need to se anything contentType ? I am using expressJs please guide